# How to design an Android application using dagger with Testing in mind

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm new to dagger, and I recently started using dagger in one of my own projects, because the concept of being able to handle the dependency injection differently for testing and production, thus being able to inject mock objects that I could use for testing was great.

I modified my application to follow the style laid out in the [dagger simple-android example](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-simple).

After setting it all up, I found that there was problems with injection, and I couldn't fully overload the injections from my production application with the testing logic.

I'm looking for advice on how to set this up in a way that my tests can actually inject differentially with mocks or other objects for testing as needed, and not be too kludgy. Currently, the **MainActivityTest** is injected correctly, but when we get to the **MainActivity**, it goes to the **PhoneApplication** and injects using it's object graph

I've included what I have below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here is my **PhoneApplication**, based on the **DemoApplication**.

```
public class PhoneApplication extends Application {
    private ObjectGraph graph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.asList(new AndroidModule(this), new PhoneModule());
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        graph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

And here's my **AndroidModule**

```
@Module(library = true, injects = MainActivity.class)
public class AndroidModule {
    private final Context context;

    public AndroidModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Allow the application context to be injected but require that it be
     * annotated with {@link ForApplication @Annotation} to explicitly
     * differentiate it from an activity context.
     */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForApplication
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    NotificationManager provideNotificationManager() {
        return (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Application.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    LocalBroadcastManager provideLocalBroadcastManager() {
        return LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ContentResolver provideContentResolver() {
        return context.getContentResolver();
    }

}
```

Based on the example, I also set up my Activities to use a base Activity.

```
public abstract class ActionBarBaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((PhoneApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

Then within my **MainActivity** I have the following

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarBaseActivity {

...

    @Inject
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
        try {
            messageReceivedIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                    Constants.EVENT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED,
                    "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd."
                            + DataProviderContract.AUTHORITY + "."
                            + DataProviderContract.MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME);

            localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(messageReceiver,
                    messageReceivedIntentFilter);
        } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                    "An error occurred registering an Intent for EVENT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
                    e);
        }
...
    }
...
}
```

This worked great and the injections slid into place really quickly, and I was ecstatic. Until I actually wanted to do some testing. The first test I wanted to perform was on my **MainActivity**.

in the `onCreate` method above, we inject with the LocalBroadcastManager from **AndroidModule**, instead of the one from **MainActivityTest**, because we don't currently have a way of telling the **PhoneApplication** or the Activities that they should use a different object graph.

```
public class MainActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    @Inject
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Inject
    ContentResolver contentResolver;

    @Inject
    MockContentResolver mockContentResolver;

    @Inject
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    private Context context;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Module(injects = { MainActivityTest.class, MainActivity.class }, library = true, overrides = true)
    static class MockModule {
        Context context;

        public MockModule(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        ContentResolver provideContentResolver() {
            return provideMockContentResolver();
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        MockContentResolver provideMockContentResolver() {
            return new MockContentResolver();
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        LocalBroadcastManager provideLocalBroadcastManager() {
            return Mockito.mock(LocalBroadcastManager.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getInstrumentation()
                .getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());

        context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new AndroidModule(context),
                new MockModule(context));
        graph.inject(this);

        super.setUp();
    };

    @MediumTest
    @UiThreadTest
    public void testIncomingMessageReceiver_onReceive()
            throws MalformedMimeTypeException {

        ArgumentCaptor<BroadcastReceiver> receiverCaptor = ArgumentCaptor
                .forClass(BroadcastReceiver.class);
        Mockito.verify(localBroadcastManager, Mockito.atLeastOnce())
                .registerReceiver(receiverCaptor.capture(),
                        Mockito.any(IntentFilter.class));
    }
}
```

This is a really simple test to get me started. I know that in the onCreate, we're going to register a BroadcastReceiver, so lets just make sure it registered. Because the test has the mockLocalBroadcastManager, but the activity uses the production LocalBroadcastManager, the verify fails.

Comment: I'm not big expert in instrumental tests. Can you check what is called first - `setUp` for test or `onCreate` for activity?

Comment: Are you sure MainActivity is being created and onCreate() is being called? According to the docs, you must invoke [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#getActivity()) from the test method for that to happen. Also, did you log out the class name of the injected broadcast receiver and verify that it's indeed using the production configuration as opposed to the override configuration which is supplying the mock?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure. Just searched over the web to find out how to use dagger properly for testing.

Nevertheless, as I understand, the `MainActivity` takes its object graph from the Application. So, that is the place where you have to insert your `MockModule`.

In order to do this, you should create a subclass of `PhoneApplication` and override `getModules()` method to return your `MockModule`. After that, you should mock application with `ActivityUnitTestCase.setApplication()` (your test should subclass `ActivityUnitTestCase` first). That should fix the issue.